# why map emplace calling rvalue constructor twice

Tags: c++11

```
class twoMem {
    int _a;
    int _b;

    public:
    twoMem() { 
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; 
    }

    twoMem(int a, int b) :_a(a), _b(b) { 
        std::cout << "constructor called" <<   std::endl; 
    }

    twoMem(const twoMem& other) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl;
        _a = other._a;
        _b = other._b;
    }

    twoMem(const twoMem&& other) {
        std::cout << "rvalue copy constructor called" << std::endl;
        _a = other._a;
        _b = other._b;
    }

    ~twoMem() {
        std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, twoMem> myMap{};
    myMap.emplace(std::make_pair("foo", twoMem{ 1, 2 }));
    return 0;
}
```

### output:

```
constructor called
rvalue copy constructor called
rvalue copy constructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```

Comment: Improve code formatting

Comment: second pass on the code formatting

Answer (score 0):

First, `make_pair` moves from `twoMem` argument into `pair<const char*, twoMem>` it returns. Second, `emplace()` moves from that into actual node.

Make it

```
myMap.emplace("foo", twoMem{ 1, 2 });
```

then [the move constructor is only called once](http://rextester.com/VMWP30249). That's kind of the point of `map::emplace`.

You can get to zero copy or move constructors [this way](http://rextester.com/NSS72471):

```
myMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple("foo"), std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```

Though arguably this cure may be worse than the disease, as now you are constructing and copying tuples around, which is likely at least as expensive as copying `twoMem`.